Shimano grip shifter too hard for son
This is a used bike that I recently got for my son. It has a shimano twist grip and a 7 speed gearset with a shimano rd-ty300 rear derailleur.
When shifting to the lower gears, it is simply too hard for my son. I even got my 9 year old to ride it, and he could barely shift it.
I oiled the cables and moved the cable guards to look for any problems on the cables but could not find any. The derailleur seems to move fine by hand without any issues. I oiled all the pivot points as well. It shifts down smoothly and very easily. When I changed the gears slowly, it is very difficult, but if I roughly change them quickly, it shifts easily. That may just be because I am an adult.
If I do need to replace the shifter, can I upgrade to a different, higher quality shifter? If that means I need to buy a new derailleur, I am ok with that as well as long as it doesn’t get too expensive. I was hoping it would be under $50 for both.

Just checking - the rider is still pedalling forward when changing gear?   I've heard from a number of new-riders taht they treat it like a car gearbox and look for some kind of Neutral by stopping pedalling, which doesn't work on a bike.

Thanks, but yes, we made sure they were pedaling.

We had the exact same issue. Grip shifters don't exist because they're good, they exist because they're cheaper to manufacture than thumb shifters. The whole idea that you have to loosen your grip from the handlebar to change the gears on a mountain bike (these aren't used in road bikes) is absurd.

@Criggie, on an IGH stop pedalling while shifting used to be the only safe way. I was a little confused, as I've only seen Revo shifters on IGH bikes before. It seems a terrible choice on a derailleur.

@Pelle terrible, but really rather common, adding up to nearly 50% of the flat bar bikes I've looked after over the years. Not surprisingly, it was mainly the cheap ones, but one was an e-bike with a throttle right next to the grip shift.  That was interesting to use

If your cable housing is lined, and the inner wire has worn through the lining, you'll have the issue you're fighting.
On a used bike, if there are any issues with shifting, cables are too cheap to NOT replace. Chances are you only need new rear housing.
I've installed a shedload of grip shifters and I like them, but they wear out fairly quickly. (a couple of years use at best)

Sadly, grip shifters are generally like this.  They're often rubbish even when new.
The only good grip shifter I found was a SRAM one with a high metal content compared to the grip shifter's plastic guts.
Good news is that its relatively easy to swap to a thumb or trigger shifter.  The hardest thing is pulling the grip off the handlebar to remove the old shifter and fit a new one.    It may be easier to replace worn or tacky hand grips at the same time and just cut the old ones off.   Same goes for the rear shift cable - if its a bit rusty or frayed, then a new inner cable is easy and cheap.
https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/shimano/SL-M315-7R.html would be a perfectly good shifter to fit, you just need it to be 7 speed.
If cost is an issue, a used shifter or an aliexpress one may be perfectly adequate and will last until rider outgrows the bike.

Thank you so much! Just an added question, do I basically just need to look for a 7 speed shifter?  The reason I ask is that I want to upgrade my schwinn as well and I really like the Shimano shifters on my wife’s Giant hybrid bike. I believe they are very similar to these that you showed here.

@Golden yes - 7 speed is the same everywhere so you can use a road or MTB shifter as long as it clamps firmly onto the handlebar.   They only diverged up at 10 speed and higher.   This sounds like a good chance to work with the rider and make a shared project of upgrading each bike in turn.

Thank you again so very much! I will post again once we have done the upgrades.

Last question, do you recommend Amazon as a retailer or another online company? My local bike shop is about 45 minutes away, and I would prefer to not make the drive.

@Golden Amazon isn't a bike shop, its just a fulfillment service.   The item is pretty much the same regardless of where you get it from, so hunt out a good price with freight/tax.    For something of this value and being fairly common, I'd probably buy new but do explore and see if you can find a bike cooperative or similar group more-local to you.

I would highly recommend a new inner cable regardless. Attempting to reuse them is fraught with difficulties, and the improvement a new cable makes to shifting makes replacement for that reason alone worthwhile.

@mattnz If replacing the shifter I'd fit a new outer as well, but that means having the right cutters.  I tend to buy parts online, either from a couple of major independent bike shops' own websites or eBay shops.  This is partly because I don't like amazon as a company, but mainly because I utterly detest the lying junk that is their "search" engine (with bike stuff as with tech you have to be very careful that the result you click on actually has the specifications you put in the search box)
